# Flutter: Speed up or delay loading of MaterialIcons-Regular.otf

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a Flutter web app. Flutter brings its `MaterialIcons-Regular.otf` file of 1.6 MB, and it adds ~1.3 sec to download time. It is loaded synchronously in a sense that nothing is showing or loading until this file is downloaded:

[image]

Fundamentally, this file should not be required for the app to start. I would much more prefer the app to load without the icons and then to add them a few seconds later. Is there a trick to load material icons asynchronously?

This is the app if it matters: https://play.beam.apache.org

Comment: I am still facing the same problem, that big file is still loaded to client's browser even after I have removed all icons from the web app!

Comment: In Flutter 3.10, the icons are tree-shaken if built with `--release` flag. In that app the file size went down to 8 kB. So this is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Download this light file:

[MaterialIcons-Regular.otf](https://github.com/mimya01/fluuter-materialicons-regular-otf/blob/main/MaterialIcons-Regular.otf)

and replace  it in :

**./build/web/assets/fonts/**

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to run `flutter build apk` in terminal.

After the operation is completed, go to `/build/app/intermediates/flutter/release/flutter_assets/fonts` in your project directory and copy the created `MaterialIcons-Regular.otf` and paste at `/build/web/assets/fonts`

[Full Article (more on flutter web optimization)](https://medium.com/@GSYTech/how-to-optimize-flutter-web-and-how-flutter-web-work-in-html-renderer-b399ffd66718)